# How to improve performance on select case?

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm out of ideas of how to improve performance for these query?

I have a query like these

```
SELECT some_field, another_field, (CASE  
    WHEN HOUR(TIMEDIFF(now(), created_at)) <= 12   
        THEN (likes_count - (HOUR(TIMEDIFF(now(), created_at)) * 0.25))  
    WHEN HOUR(TIMEDIFF(now(), created_at)) > 12   
        AND HOUR(TIMEDIFF(now(), created_at)) <= 48   
        THEN (likes_count -(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(now(), created_at)) * 0.5)) 
    ELSE (likes_count - (HOUR(TIMEDIFF(now(), created_at)) * 3))  
        END) as total  
FROM some_table  
WHERE likes_count >= '30'  
ORDER BY total DESC, created_at DESC  
LIMIT 10
```

It took almost 6 second in my production server, the problem is these query is located at my homepage (index)
While the query if not using select case only took like 0.05 second..
I've tried to improve performance by using memcached so the apps doesn't always query the database, but the problem is still there when querying database, 6 second...

Anybody has a suggestion on how to improve these query?

Here is my explain query

`| id | select_type | table    | type   | possible_keys     | key                 | key_len | ref                              | rows  | Extra                       |

|  1 | SIMPLE      | journals | ref    | container,indx_journal_status,indx_journal_like_count | indx_journal_status | 32      | const                            | 22369 | Using where; Using filesort |`

Here is my table structure

`| Field                       | Type                  | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |

+-----------------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+

| id                          | bigint(20) unsigned   | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |

| title                   | varchar(20)           | NO   | MUL | Status            |                |

| description                | bigint(20)            | YES  |     | NULL              |                |

| created_at                  | timestamp             | YES  | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |

| likes_count                 | int(11)               | NO   | MUL | 0                 |                |`

Comment: You need to post table structure and what `EXPLAIN` output shows

Comment: Your entire query performance depends on created_at and likes_count fields. Are these indexed?

Comment: @sandeepKumar yes both are indexed

Comment: I see the expression "HOUR(TIMEDIFF(now(), created_at))" is used 6 times in your query and I dont know how to minimize it. But i can suggest an alternate solution:
Alter some_table to have another field "total" and update this field with your query every 5 min or 1 hour using cron as a background job and from main app re-write the query for the necessary requirement.

Comment: @SandepKumar yes i think that's the solution for read, but will it affect my performance overall? if i make a cronjob to update every record on my table every 1 hour to decrease "point" field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i've been able to reduce query load by restarting one of my backend app server.
Looks like there is a query/process that took a long time to run.
Now my query took 1.2second, but i'll still try to improve my app/query performance so it will be able to run under 0.5second.